# Pass ORM object to router in express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

In my index.ts I am initializing a typeORM instance and I would like this initialized object to be available in my routes. How can I accomplish this?

Right now my index.ts looks as follows:

```
export const startServer = async () => {
  await appDataSource.initialize();
  await appDataSource.runMigrations();

  const app = express();

  // set up REST endpoints
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use('/kyc', kycRouter)

  //set up graphql endpoint
  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [UserResolver, MarketDataResolver],
      validate: false,
    }),
    context: () => ({ em: appDataSource.manager }),
  });

  await apolloServer.start();

  // run the server
  const port = 4000

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("server started");
  });

};

startServer().catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Where appDataSource is my typeORM instance. I would like to be able to use appDataSource.manager in all my routes (for now the only one I have is /kyc). With apollo and graphql I am just using `context: () => ({ em: appDataSource.manager }),` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware to add properties to the request object that will be passed along to the different endpoints. The code below adds the manager to `req.datesourceManager` but this could be any name you want.

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
req.datasourceManager = appDataSource.manager
next();
});
```

---

Edit to make it work with typescript

Add the following to the tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions":{
  "typeRoots": [
    "./src/custom_typings",
    "./node_modules/@types",
  ],
}
```

And create following folders/files:

```
src
├── custom_typings
│   ├── express
│   │   └── index.d.ts
│   └── index.d.ts
```

The `src/custom_typings/index.d.ts` is empty but was necessary to get rid of some problems in vscode. In the `src/custom_typings/express/index.d.ts` add the following but of code:

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      dataSource: DataSource;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when I try this I get the error `Property 'dataSource' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)
`

Comment: If you used exactly the code I provided, you should use datasourceManager as explained. If you changed it to dataSource, make sure the middle ware is set before the routes

Comment: I have tried both. The problem is with typescript. I am trying to extend the type definition of the request object but I am not successful. I tried to add `    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/custom_typings",]` to my tsconfig and then add a file there called express.d.ts where I do `declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    dataSource: DataSource;
  }
}
` But it is still not working....

Comment: I opened a new question for this typescript error https://stackoverflow.com/q/72897818/4923949